# Login using laravel5.2

Tags: laravel-5

Hi I'm new to laravel and I'm using the laravel5.2 version.

Actually I have this registration form too. But no problem in registration.

My question is that I'm looking for a simple and understandable code in login. I've seen it somewhere while googling but I think that one is not laravel5.2.

I just get the reference code in some examples and test it into my login app. I'm using a repositories on it. I've got some errors. It says

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 FatalErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 126: Class '\App\User' not found
```

I'm not sure why the error says app user not found. Here is my code below

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;
use App\Repositories\Contracts\loginRepositoryInterface;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Users;
use DB;
use Session;
use Auth;


class loginRepository implements loginRepositoryInterface{

    protected $request;
    //Initialize request instance
    public function __construct(Request $request){
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function loginAuth(){
        //validate login
        $validator = app('validator')->make($this->request->all(), [
            'emailAddress' => 'email|required',
            'password'  => 'required']);

        //if validator fails then return response error
        if($validator->fails())
            return redirect()->route('get.login')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

        try{
            $pwd = $this->request->get('password');
            $sha1 = sha1($pwd);
            $userdata = array(
                'emailAddress' =>$this->request->get('emailAddress'),
                'password'  =>$sha1
            );

            if(Auth::attempt($userdata)){
                return redirect()->intended('get.dashboard');
            }else{
                return redirect()->route('get.login')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
            }



        }catch(\Exception $e){
            return redirect()->route('get.login')->withErrors(["error"=>"Could not add details! Please try again."])->withInput();
        }

    }


    //postCreate
    public function postCreate($screen){
        switch($screen){
            case 'auth':
            return $this->loginAuth();
            break;
        }
    }

    //getLoginView
    public function getCreate(){
        return view('login');
    }
}
```

In method public function loginAuth()

My routes

```
 //postLogin
    Route::post('/login/{screen}', [
        'as'    => 'post.login.auth',
        'uses'  => 'loginController@postCreate'
    ]);

    //getLoginView
    Route::get('/login', [
        'as'    => 'get.login',
        'uses'  => 'loginController@getCreate'
    ]);
```

Can some one help me on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the `\App\User` model in `app/User.php` from the looks of the code you posted above, you seem to have `\App\Users` not `\App\User`

Comment: i tried to add an App\User.php file and when i fired the login it redirects back to /login

Comment: Clear your log file then see what happens when you try to login, do you get an error?

Comment: Also, why exactly are you hashing your password with sha1? Laravel has inbuilt hashing, just pass the raw password

Comment: i also change the sha1 into hash the laravel in registration and when i fired in the login it redirects back to /login

Comment: Its redirecting because its an invalid login. Stop using sha1 leave it as it is.

Comment: You should mark the answer though because it solves your initial problem

Comment: i change the sha1 into hash but when i tried it redirects to login hmmm

Comment: i think i got it correcty only with the emailAddress i got it wrong thanks for your help